# Refresh the view to avoid the error another process has updated ARRegister

Tags: acumatica

Upon deletion of my custon item LELettering in which I have a view with ARRegister lines, I want to :
- Reverse the payment application for every Invoice ARRegister lines for the payment also included in my ARRegister lines. 
- Clean the LetteringCD I did put in a custom field in my ARRegister extension.

Now when I pick one or the other alone, it works.
My problem is when I do both : reverseapplication() do it's job, but this, as a side effect, updates the ARRegister records when I call the reverseapplication method from the ARPaymentEntry.

Which lead to an error : "Another process has update the ARRegister record and your changes will be lost", when I try to update the ARRegister records to clean my custom field LetteringCD.

I think my problem is my view Lines is not refreshed once reverseApplication is called, so it still has the not yet updated records of ARRegister.

I tried ClearQueryCache() but it doesnt seem to work, how to I force a refresh on my view Lines so I can update them again ?

```
        public PXSelect<LELettering> Piece;
        public PXSelect<ARRegister> Lines;

protected virtual void LELettering_RowDeleting(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Cancel the lettering by removing every LetteringCD from the ARRegister lines and reverse application paiements
        cancelLettering();
    }

        protected void cancelLettering()
        {
            reverseApplication();
            eraseLetteringCD();
        }

       protected void reverseApplication()
        {
            string refNbr = "";
            List<ARRegister> lines = new List<ARRegister>();
            foreach (ARRegister line in PXSelect<ARRegister, Where<ARRegisterLeExt.lettrageCD, 
                Equal<Required<ARRegisterLeExt.lettrageCD>>>>.Select(this, Piece.Current.LetteringCD))
            {
                if (line.DocType == "PMT") refNbr = line.RefNbr;
                else lines.Add(line);
            }
            ARPaymentEntry graphPmt = getGraphPayment(refNbr, "PMT");
            foreach(ARAdjust line in graphPmt.Adjustments_History.Select())
            {
                graphPmt.Adjustments_History.Current = line;
                graphPmt.reverseApplication.Press();
            }
            graphPmt.release.Press();
            graphPmt.Actions.PressSave();
        }
// Here is my problem
        protected void eraseLetteringCD()
        {
            foreach (var line in Lines.Select())
            {
                line.GetItem<ARRegister>().GetExtension<ARRegisterLeExt>().LettrageCD = null;
                Lines.Current = Lines.Update(line);
            }
            Actions.PressSave();
        }

        protected ARPaymentEntry getGraphPayment(string refNbr, string docType)
        {
            ARPaymentEntry graphPmt = CreateInstance<ARPaymentEntry>();
            ARPayment pmt = PXSelect<ARPayment, Where<ARPayment.refNbr, Equal<Required<ARPayment.refNbr>>,
                                And<ARPayment.docType, Equal<Required<ARPayment.docType>>>>>
                                    .Select(this, refNbr, docType);
            if (pmt == null) throw new PXException(Constantes.errNotFound);
            graphPmt.Document.Current = pmt;
            return graphPmt;
        }
```

Edit: 
The problem comes from the fact the records ARRegister are saved two times, once with the reversepaymentapplication, and once in the eraseLetteringCD, but I dont know how to avoid this in my case.

Comment: FYI we have a new blog page explaining the cause of this generic error and possible solutions to fix it: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/03/another-process-has-addedupdateddeleted.html

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt really give a solution, I know why it happens, but I dont know how to avoid saving my records two times in my case.

Comment: most likely because you are creating a graph instance and using it to update and then later on using a different graph instance to update the same records. The 2nd call needs to refresh the loaded records after the first graph persisted the records. Ideally you would want to have the same graph persist the same records (and should automatically avoid the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things I might try...

I do see that there are multiple graphs involved. The second graph will need to refresh the results before it can process. There are a few ways of doing this that I try...

You can try to clear the query cache as shown below. My guess when you call Lines.Select it has an old cached value?

```
protected void cancelLettering()
{
    reverseApplication();

    Lines.Cache.ClearQueryCache()

    eraseLetteringCD();
}
```

I find it helpful some items in reverse if the select is not returning the cached results to find the cached row myself. The reverse could be to use `PXSelectReadonly<>` as your foreach select statement as this should use the records from the DB vs any cached values.

```
protected void eraseLetteringCD()
{
    // Also try PXSelectReadonly<> in place of Lines.Select()
    foreach (ARRegister line in Lines.Select())
    {
        //Get cached row
        var cachedRow = (ARRegister)Lines.Cache.Locate(line) ?? line;

        cachedRow.GetExtension<ARRegisterLeExt>().LettrageCD = null;
        Lines.Update(cachedRow );
    }
    Actions.PressSave();
}
```

After the first press save you could also try to just clear the cache and the query cache to setup for the next call. Ideally if possibly just do one persist.

If the first graph is running a long operation you can make the code pause to wait for the operation to complete. This would be useful when using multiple graphs. The second graph persist should not run until the first long running process has finished. Example using the ID of your *graphPmt* instance:

```
graphPmt.release.Press();
PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(graphPmt.UID)
```

Comment: I get a cast error : Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Data.PXResult`1[PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister]' to type 'PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister'. When trying to cast (ARregister) Lines.Cache ...

Also I already tried unsuccessfully to use : Lines.Cache.ClearQueryCache();

The problem is the arregister is updated by the releasepaymentapplication() and persisted, isnt there a way to force a refresh on my view so it takes the persisted records instead of the cached ones ?

Comment: I see you are using a graph "ARPaymentEntry graphPmt" vs the existing graph. Are you persisting accross 2 graphs then this would explain why you are getting the error. The 2nd graph needs to reload the records persisted by the first. You can also try PXSelectReadonly vs PXSelect to make sure you are getting the DB record. Try that in place of Lines.Select() in your 2nd call which is failing.

Comment: Yes I persist across two graphs, because I need to use the reversepaymentapplication method of the ARPaymentEntry graph, and its Release method. All of this while being on my other custom graph.
When I use PXSelectReadonly I dont get the error anymore, but it seems it prevents my payment to get released. (It puts the ARAdjust in "document to apply" tab, but doesnt release it, whereas if I do use a PXSelect it releases it correctly, then proceed to fail at updating the letteringCD field). Is it because the relase is a PXLongOperation and as I update my ARRegister, it makes this operation fail?

Comment: ah yea that could be. You can wait for the operation to complete by using PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(graphPmt.UID); after graphPmt.release.Press(); and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks, the combination of PXSelectReadonly and PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion did the trick :) would you mind editing your answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: Perfect. Will do